# systemd keeps unmounting a removable drive

Tags: mount, systemd, vfat

I have following line in /etc/fstab:

```
UUID=E0FD-F7F5 /mnt/zeno vfat noauto,utf8,user,rw,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0113,dmask=0002 0 0
```

The partition is freshly created by `gnome-disks` under the respective user, and spans the whole card.

Now: Running `mount /mnt/zeno` as user (1000) succeeds, but right after that I find out that it's actually *not* mounted: following `umount /mnt/zeno` fails with `umount: /mnt/zeno: not mounted`.  When watching `journalctl -f`, I can see following messages appear when mounting:

```
[...] kernel: SELinux: initialized (dev mmcblk0p1, type vfat), uses genfs_contexts
[...] systemd[1]: Unit mnt-zeno.mount is bound to inactive service. Stopping, too.
[...] systemd[1]: Unmounting /mnt/zeno...
[...] systemd[1]: Unmounted /mnt/zeno.
```

So it seems that systemd indeed keeps unmounting the drive, but I can't find out why.  I don't remember creating any custom ".mount" files.  I tried to find something in /etc/systemd and in my home folder but did not find anything.

So what is this "mnt-zeno.mount" file and how can I review it?  And most importantly, how can I mount the drive?

Comment: What is the output of `systemctl --all`  Warning it will be long, but we're looking for the service that mnt-zeno.mount depends on.

Comment: @eyoung100 is this the right line? `dev-disk-by\x2dlabel-zeno.device loaded    active   plugged   /dev/disk/by-label/zeno`

Comment: @don_crissti no dupes in fstab.  daemon-reload helped, though, could you post it as answer (perhaps with some brief explanation)?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

`mnt-zeno.mount` was created by [`systemd-fstab-generator`](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-fstab-generator.html).  According to Jonathan de Boyne Pollard's [explanation on debian-user mailing list](https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2014/11/msg00033.html):

> [systemd-fstab-generator is] a program that reads /etc/fstab at boot time
>   and generates units that translate fstab records to the systemd way of
>   doing things [.....]
>
> The systemd way of doing things is mount and device units, per the
>   systemd.mount(5) and systemd.device(5) manual pages. In the raw systemd
>   way of doing things, there's a device unit named "dev-sde1.device" which
>   is a base requirement for a mount unit named "media-lumix\x2dphotos.mount".

After altering `fstab` one should either run `systemctl daemon-reload` (this makes `systemd` to reparse `/etc/fstab` and pick up the changes) or reboot.

Answer (score 5):

For people who come here via a google search (like me), the developers have known about this problem for almost 5(!) years as of writing this and still nobody tries to fix it. https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/1741

Workaround: Often, restarting the systemd daemon via `systemctl daemon-reload` solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**systemd: Unmounting /boot**

One of the Redhat 7 Linux VM running on Azure platform. recently. i have restored the data from old backup with the help of below mentioned URL Azure KB article.

**https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-restore-files-from-vm**

Post restoration activity Azure unmounted the disk automatically from the linux VM.

After that i dont see /boot filesystem on the server and it's unmounted automatically.

below is the error message starting seeing  in the /var/log/messages

```
Dec 14 15:04:00 rhellinuxdbprodserver systemd: Unmounting /boot...
Dec 14 15:04:00 rhellinuxdbprodserver kernel: XFS (sda1): Unmounting Filesystem
Dec 14 15:04:00 rhellinuxdbprodserver systemd: Unmounted /boot.
```

To fix the issue i just reparse the  "systemctl daemon-reload" post that /boot filesystem mounted properly.

Pre-Artifact

```
[root@rhellinuxdbprodserver boot]# df -Th | grep -v tmpfs
Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2      xfs        64G   51G   14G  79% /
/dev/sdb1      ext4      111G   17G   89G  16% /mnt/resource
```

```
[root@rhellinuxdbprodserver boot]# systemctl daemon-reload
```

```
[root@rhellinuxdbprodserver boot]# mount -a
```

Post-Artifact

```
[root@rhellinuxdbprodserver boot]# df -Th | grep -v tmpfs
Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2      xfs        64G   51G   14G  79% /
/dev/sdb1      ext4      111G   17G   89G  16% /mnt/resource
/dev/sda1      xfs       497M  203M  294M  41% /boot
```