# Why is systemd unmounting my fuse file systems right after I mount them?

Tags: systemd, fuse, unmounting

I am trying to troubleshoot [an issue](https://github.com/bazil/fuse/issues/89) with a fuse library, where my fuse file system is mysteriously unmounted shortly after mounting it.

After screwing around with a bespoke `unmount` executable that logged evidence about its invoker, I found that systemd is the culprit. Indeed `/var/log/syslog` contains lots of messages like this:

```
Jun  8 06:39:41 ubuntu systemd[1]: Unit tmp-fusetest301566509.mount is bound to inactive unit dev-fuse.device. Stopping, too.
Jun  8 06:39:41 ubuntu systemd[1]: Unmounting /tmp/fusetest301566509...
```

I don't know the first thing about configuring systemd. Where should I look to figure out why it thinks it is allowed to unmount my file systems without me telling it to?

I'm running Ubuntu 15.04:

```
% uname -a
Linux ubuntu 3.19.0-16-generic #16-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 30 16:09:58 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**Update**: I should clarify that there are no entries related to this path or `/dev/fuse` in `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: Maybe related to http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169909/systemd-keeps-unmounting-a-removable-drive

Comment: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=187134

Comment: Thanks, but those appear to be caused by a need to rescan /etc/fstab. I don't have any relevant entries there. (I've updated the question.)

Comment: Okay, so I take it back: I tried `systemctl daemon-reload` anyway, and the problem appears to have gone away. But I don't understand why. :-/

Comment: Nevermind, I had mixed up two things I tried. The actual reason it appears to have stopped is that I updated my fuse program to set a name for the file system, rather than using the default of `/dev/fuse`. That appears to keep systemd out of its business.